# How to put text bocks over image on a fixed background?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to put news titles on image background like this:

[image]

What I came up with, is this:

```
 <div class="image-container">
     <a href="/path"><img src="/path/to/img" class="img-thumbnail"></a> 
     <div class="text-block">
         <div class="bottom-right">My News Title</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.text-block {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
     opacity: .8; 
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
}

.bottom-right {
  color: black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Which results in this:

[image]

My problem is how to modify my code so that the title appears on a semi-transparent background which covers 1/3 of the bottom of the block, like the coffee picture above?

Comment: The image is more decorative than informative; use CSS `background-image`.

Comment: @zero298 It's true the image is decorative, but I appreciate if you elaborate your answer with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clean up the markup a bit and use a simple container element with a title (e.g. a div and a heading).

As noted by @zero298 if the image doesn't convey any information it should be defined as a background of the container

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpveBX)

---

**Markup**

```
<div style="background-image: url(https://.../coffee-serum-300x240.jpg)">
  <h2>
       The title of this article  
       may span across several lines. 
       but it's always anchored on the bottom
   </h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 240px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

div h2 {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 1em 3em 1em;
}
```

---

**Final result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since the image is decorative, use `background-image`:

```css
.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.text{
background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
<div class="text">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <p>Foo bar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following :

```
.bottom-right {
color: black;
position: absolute;
bottom: 50%;
right: 50%;
background-color: #fff; }

.image-container {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
color: white; }

.text-block {
position: absolute;
top: 95%;
left: 50%;
height: 40%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
```

Also, I think this is very helpful form w3schools. 
 https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp